# Why am I getting the message "No module named httplib2"?

Tags: python, macbook

Can anyone explain why I'm being told there is no httplib2 module even though it comes up under the pip list?

```
Johns-MacBook-Air-8:~ jyamamo$ pip list
httplib2 (0.9.2)
pip (8.1.2)
setuptools (20.10.1)
```

---

```
Johns-MacBook-Air-8:PythonOmekaApiToCsv-master jyamamo$ python omekacsv.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "omekacsv.py", line 3, in <module>
    from omekaclient import OmekaClient
  File "/Users/jyamamo/Desktop/PythonOmekaApiToCsv-master/omekaclient.py", line 1, in <module>
    import httplib2
ImportError: No module named httplib2
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using python 2 or python 3?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have 2 python versions installed. Try `which pip` and `python -v` to see what those *aliases* refers to. Usually pip refers to pip3, which installs for python3, 'python' usually refers to python2.

Options :

- install `httplib2` for python2 using `pip2 install httplib2` or system package manager.

Or

- Use python3

Comment: It doesn't like "pip2" (command not found). Python3 is in there, and "python3" at the command prompt leads to the acknowledgement "Python 3.5.2". However "python -v" still shows python 2.7 as the version being used. How do I either get pip2 running or get python to switch from 2.7 to 3.5.2?

Comment: If you want `pip2` install it, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11272201/1509809) for help. My advise would be to use [virtualenv](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5177027/1509809).

[How to install pip with python3?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6587528/1509809)